# System.Web.Http.Ok does not resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have installed `AspNetWebApi 5.2.3` using Nuget Package Manager in my ASP.Net MVC project however `System.Web.Http.Ok` does not resolve.
My project is configured for .Net Framework 4.6.1. I'm going to use below syntax in my code, however `Ok` does not resolve:

```
return Ok(new { Status = 1, CustomerId = 1});
```

What I have missed here?

Comment: Have you tried importing the namespace with a `using` statement?

Comment: I have imported `using System.Web.Http;`.

Comment: Does your controller inherit from `ApiController`?

Comment: Does your project reference [System.Web.Http](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: @benjrb Nope. That was the point. please put this as answer.

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ok` method is available on `ApiController` in the `System.Web.Http` namespace which you correctly reference. When adding Web API to your application you need to make sure that your API controllers inherit from the `ApiController` class instead of `Controller` for MVC.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: And one another point, when I Inherited from ApiController, I should change return value of my methods to `IHttpActionResult` and my controller will not accessible any more! I mean when I call the same route before this change everything was fine but now calling my controller I face ` The resource cannot be found.` error prompt

Comment: Try `api/` before your route. It might be looking for your controller using MVC

Comment: It also requires register routes for web api to `Application_Start()` method as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936073/1080355)